# Algorithm for selecting tiles outwards center point in a 512*512 map

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I've got a specific problem. My data (map) in mysql is as follows

```
id     table_row table_col tile_type
1      1         1         0
2      2         1         0
3      3         1         0
...    ...       ...       0
512    512       1         0
513    1         2         0
514    2         2         0
515    3         2         0
...    ...       ...       0
...    512       2         0
...    1         3         0
...    2         3         0
...    3         3         0
...    ...       ...       0
...    512       3         0
...    1         4         0
```

Map is 512*512. I need to come up with an algorithm that selects tiles from the centre(or near centre 256*256) point. So it should look something like

```
256*256 first - once selected we can update tile_type to 1
255*256 second - update tile_type to 1
256*255 third - update tile_type to 1
257*256 fourth - update tile_type to 1
256*257 fifth - update tile_type to 1
```

etc. or similar, but it has to start filling in tiles from centre outwards in all directions (can be random). Any ideas appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks a few details, but I am assuming you are asking a means of generating an `id` that is close to the center of your 512x512 grid.

It appears your grid is enumerated in a particular manner: each column is enumerated in increasing order of `table_row` values, and the enumeration of columns is done in increasing order of `table_col` values.

Consequently, we can already know the `id` of the cell for which the `table_row` and `table_col` values are 256: it is `255 x 512 + 256`. That is correct, because there are 255 full columns that were enumerated before enumeration started for `table_col` value 256, and each of those columns had 512 rows in them. Finally, within this column, we are interested in row #256.

A more generalized version of this would look like below.

```
((num_cols + 1) / 2 - 1) * num_rows + (num_rows + 1) / 2
```

You don't need to care all that much about the +1s and -1s: they are just a numerical hack to handle odd num_rows and num_cols values.

Anyways, to introduce a proximity measure, you can just use two random variables. A random variable `P` can represent the distance to the center in terms of colums. (i.e. how far the `table_col` of the point with the generated `id` will be from the `table_col` value of the center of the grid) Another random variable `Q` can represent the distance to the center in terms of rows.

```
((num_cols + 1) / 2 - 1 + P) * num_rows + ((num_rows + 1) / 2 + Q)
```

Then you can just generate values for P and Q based on your needs, and get the `id` of a cell that is P colums and Q rows away from the center of the grid.

Comment: That looks good thanks. I'll run it in a bit, although not too sure about +1s and -1s as it seems to do a job without. I guess I'll populate entire grid using  extracted IDs and see if I run into problems. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try Below query.

```
 SELECT (MAX(t.`row`+1)/2), (MAX(t.`column`+1)/2) INTO @max_row, @max_col
 FROM tiles t;

 SELECT t.`row`, t.`column`, ceil(IF(ABS(@max_row - t.`row`) < ABS(@max_col - t.`column`), ABS(@max_col - t.`column`), ABS(@max_row - t.`row`))) as tbl_order
 FROM tiles t
 ORDER BY 3
```